# How Do we Interpret This Complex C++ Preprocessor Macro Replacement

Tags: c++, macros, c-preprocessor

I am studying the C++ standard on how the C++ preprocessor handles macro substitution in detail (I need to implement a subset of the C++ preprocessor myself). And here is an example I created for my studying:

```
  #define a x
  #define x(x,y) x(x+a, y+1)

  a(x(90, 80), a(1,2))
```

By asking VC++ 2010 to generate the preprocessor output file, I found that the above `a(x(90, 80), a(1,2))` becomes this:

```
90(90+x, 80+1)(90(90+x, 80+1)+x, 1(1+x, 2+1)+1);
```

But how does the preprocessor come up with this output? The rules are too complicated to comprehend. Can someone explain all the steps the preprocessor has done to come up with such a result?

Comment: For starters, macros are not applied recursively.

Comment: But there is no warning/error generated by VC++ for recursive macro

Comment: I didn't imply that there should be. I'm just saying `x(x+a, y+1)` cannot possibly expand using that `x(x,y)` definition, which narrows what `x` can be expanded to down to two possibilities.

Comment: @JavaMan, what sort of warning would you like to get? About your using the same name for a FLM parameter as the FLM itself? (FLM = function-like macro)

Comment: I dont expect any warning/error, and there wasn't any. I just want to UNDERSTAND what rules are used to come up with the result. (so that I can implement a mini-preprocessor myself)

Comment: @JavaMan, to say frankly, the rules are pretty complicated. They function quite intuitively in simple cases, but in cases like yours they're hell. The C language standard takes 13 pages to lay them out.

Comment: Just a (very) small detail: it is impossible the preprocessor outputted the semi-colon at the end of the output: either you forgot it in the first code block, or it is a typo (or an habit^^) in the last block.

Comment: @Synxis, yes, my typo and my fingers auto insert a ; without my knowledge

Comment: Does "CPP standard" mean "C++ standard"? The term "CPP" is commonly used to refer to the C preprocessor.

Comment: @Keith Thompson CPP = C++. That's the sense for it, at least nowadays (you're the first person I encounter and that say cpp = c preprocessor)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Old answer, order is not exact (see edit):

> Let's start from your expression:
>
> ```
> a(x(90, 80), a(1, 2))
> ```
>
> Now, since we have `#define a x`, it gets expanded to:
>
> ```
>   x(x(90, 80), x(1, 2))
> //  ^^^^^^^^^  ^^^^^^^
> //   arg 'x'    arg 'y'
> ```
>
> We can apply the definition of `x(x,y)`, which is `#define x(x,y) x(x+a, y+1)`:
>
> ```
> x(90, 80)(x(90, 80)+a, x(1, 2)+1)
> ```
>
> There is another pass that will expand `x(...)`. You can also notice that the `+a` that > was in the previous expression was expanded to `+x`:
>
> ```
>   90(90+a, 80+1)(90(90+a, 80+1)+x, 1(1+a, 2+1)+1)
> //                             ^^
> //                          expanded
> ```
>
> Last: the `+a` that remains are expanded to `+x`:
>
> ```
>   90(90+x, 80+1)(90(90+x, 80+1)+x, 1(1+x, 2+1)+1)
> //     ^^             ^^              ^^
> //  expanded       expanded        expanded
> ```
>
> I hope there are no errors.

Please note that your definition of `x(x,y)` is quite ambiguous (for humans): the macro name and a parameter share the same name. Note that even withouth that, macros are not recursive, so if you had

```
#define x(u,v) x(u+a, b+1)
```

it would *not* expand to something like

```
x(u+a+a+a+a, b+1+1+1+1)
```

This is because when the macro `x` is defined, its name is not 'available' to the inner macro definition.

Another small note: for gcc, the output is not exactly the same, as gcc add spaces between replaced tokens (but if you remove them it will be the same as msvc).

***EDIT***: from the comments of dyp, this order is not the exact one. In fact, *parameters are expanded first and then substituted in the macro expression*. The last part of the sentence is important: that means that the macro parameter list is not re-evalued. Think of it as: macro gets expanded with placeholders in lieu of the parameters, then arguments are expanded, and then the placeholders are replaced by their respective argument. So, in short, that is equivalent to what I explained before, but here is the right order (detailed operations):

```
> Expansion of a(x(90, 80), a(1, 2))
    > Substitution of 'a' into 'x' (now: 'x(x(90, 80), a(1, 2))')
    > Expansion of x(x(90, 80), a(1, 2)) [re-scan]
        > Macro 'x(X, Y)' is expanded to 'X(X+a,Y+1)'
        > Expansion of 'x(90,80)' (first argument)
            > Macro 'x(X,Y)' is expanded to 'X(X+a,Y+1)'
            > Argument '90' does not need expansion (ie, expanded to same)
            > Argument '80' does not need expansion (ie, expanded to same)
            > Substitution with 'X=90' and 'Y=80': '90(90+a, 80+1)'
            > Re-scan of result (ignoring macro name 'x')
                > Substitution of 'a' into 'x': '90(90+x, 80+1)'
        > Expansion of 'a(1,2)' (second argument)
            > Substitution of 'a' into 'x'
            > Expansion of 'x(1,2)' [re-scan]
                > Macro 'x(X,Y)' is expanded to 'X(X+a,Y+1)'
                > Argument '1' does not need expansion (ie, expanded to same)
                > Argument '2' does not need expansion (ie, expanded to same)
                > Substitution with 'X=1' and 'Y=2': '1(1+a, 2+1)'
                > Re-scan of result (ignoring macro name 'x')
                    > Substitution of 'a' into 'x': '1(1+x, 2+1)'
        > Substitution with X='90(90+x, 80+1)' and Y='1(1+x, 2+1)'
          Result: '90(90+x, 80+1)(90(90+x, 80+1)+a, 1(1+x, 2+1)+1)'
        > Re-scan of result
            > Substitution of 'a' into 'x'
              Result: '90(90+x, 80+1)(90(90+x, 80+1)+x, 1(1+x, 2+1)+1)'
Last result is result of whole expansion:
    90(90+x, 80+1)(90(90+x, 80+1)+x, 1(1+x, 2+1)+1)
```

Comment: Ok, I was using the term "pass" quite informally, I will reformulate when my Wifi network will be stable.

Comment: @dyp I agree for the non-recursive explanation, that's roughly what I put in my answer. However, I think that normally the macro is expanded **before** the parameters (and that makes more sense). I have a [small test here](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/a9d14b599aacad80), I just hope there are no errors ;). (and to be more precise, I think some preprocessor expand macro first, some others expand params first, for ex the msvc one).

Comment: @dyp Here is another example: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/bc2ca5a04f21c8f9

Comment: Ok, after having made [another example](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/5fc75abbb0fc51f7) and read yours, I think we're talking about the same thing ;). The standard method is 'macro first' I think (maybe with some little corner-cases, but this approximation is easier to understand).

Comment: Yeah, I think that description "Standard expansion" nails it :) (What's not present in your example is the non-expansion of the original macro in the re-scan though.)

Comment: @dyp I added the detailed expansion, as you pointed, thanks for the comments ! :).

Comment: Ok, I'll start removing the comments ;) .. I think this expansion: *"Expansion of 'x(1,2)'"* also requires a re-scan after the preceding replacement of `a`.

Comment: *"Expansion of 'x(1,2)'"* is the re-scan after the substitution, I made this clearer :)